# API-client authentications with JWT — Node/TypeScript

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt

I have an API and a web client developed using node and TypeScript. Users can authenticate using JWT. The system works, but I would like to know if it is secure, or if it has flaws:

The system is as follows:

1. Client POST to /login endpoint on API
2. On API, when POST /login request is received, a JWT token is generated using some user data as content, and a secret string that is stored as an environment variable:

   ```
   // SECRET is an environment variable == "bd0b2760-5869-11ec-bf63-0242ac130002"

   const userData = {
     id: 1,
     name: "John Doe",
   };

   const token = jwt.sign(JSON.stringify(userData), SECRET);
   ```
3. In the response for POST /login API sends two cookies: one holding the token, and another one with raw user data:

   ```
   return res
     .cookie('sessionData', userData, {
       httpOnly: true,
       path: '/',
       domain: "example.com",
     })
     .cookie('sessionToken', token, {
       httpOnly: true,
       path: '/',
       domain: "example.com",
     }).send();
   ```
4. The client receives the token. The client can be sure that `sessionToken` is valid, as it was sent by the API. It wont verify it, as to do it the SECRET is needed, and we don't want to expose it to the client.
5. On reload, client will use the `sessionData` cookie to know that user is logged in, using this data to load the client-side user data.
6. As those cookies are http cookies, both cookies are attached to every request send to the API, and are received by the API. On every request to endpoints requiring auth, the API will decrypt `sessionToken` and match it against `sessionToken` cookie: if they doesnt match, API will delete cookies in the response, effectively logging out the client.

   ```
   // SECRET is an environment variable == "bd0b2760-5869-11ec-bf63-0242ac130002"
   const sessionToken = req.cookies.sessionToken;
   const sessionData = req.cookies.sessionData;
   const decodedToken = jwt.verify(sessionToken, SECRET);

   if(decodedToken.id !== sessionData.id || decodedToken.name !== sessionData.name ) {
     return res
       .clearCookie('sessionToken', { path: '/', domain: "example.com" })
       .clearCookie('sessionData', { path: '/', domain: "example.com" })
   }
   ```

As previously said, this system works, and it seems secure. But maybe I'm missing something, so better ask. All code is kinda pseudocode.

Any help will be welcome!

Comment: It is secure but how secure depends on your users. If a user logs in and leaves their terminal it is possible someone could get ahold of their `sessionToken` and use it maliciously. The cookie adds a level of security on top of this but is not bulletproof. I would recommend a time out system that logs users out if they are idle for X amount of time. It all really depends on how sensitive your information is and what level of security you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot @CraigHowell. Actually I covered this case, my cookies expires after 48 hrs. although didnt show it in the example

Comment: Also, as they are httpCookies, I think is not possible to use the cookie data to send a request, as only cookies from a specific server are allowed

Answer (score 0):

> It wont verify it, as to do it the SECRET is needed, and we don't want to expose it to the client.

If you want the client to be able to verify this JWT you can use asymmetric signing. Then the client uses a public key, which can be used only to verify that the JWT is OK. It can't be used to sign new JWTs.

> On reload, client will use the sessionData cookie to know that user is logged in, using this data to load the client-side user data.

You're using http only cookies so that won't work. Your client is not able to read that cookie.

> the API will decrypt sessionToken

Minor thing, but worth remembering - the API will `decode` the sessionToken cookie, not `decrypt`. Signed JWTs are encoded, not encrypted. You can create encrypted JWTs (JWE), in which case no one, apart from the API will be able to read the content of the token, but JWEs are much harder to maintain.

> the API will decrypt sessionToken and match it against sessionData cookie

I don't see how this gives you any additional security. The session token is a signed JWT, so you can easily verify it to check whether it's been tampered with. If someone managed to steal the sessionToken cookie they might as well have stolen the sessionData cookie and use them together. You're using http only cookies so XSS won't be able to steal the contents of those cookies. You could also use `secure` flag to make sure that those cookies are not sent through unencrypted connections.